# how can i send JS data to django?

Tags: javascript, python, django

```
var typingTimer;
var doneTypingInterval = 500;
var searchedValue;

$("#trackName").focusin(function(){
    $(this).keyup(function(){
        clearTimeout(typingTimer);
        if($(this).val()){
            typingTimer = setTimeout(doneTyping, doneTypingInterval);
        }
    });

});


function doneTyping(){

    searchedValue = ($("#trackName").val());
    return searchedValue;
}
```

actually my aim is to get this searchedValue variable in django so that i can use this variable to access some song name from my django database.

for eg: if i type "fad" in input element then `searchedValue = "fad"` then i want this variable in django so that i can use database query to access all the song with name "fad"

thanks for the help in advance

Answer (score 1):

To communicate with django you have two choices, one would be to use a custom template tag, in which you can pass the variable you want and make it do a database fetch for example in this case.

[Here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/custom-template-tags/) you can see more info about custom template tags

Another way of achieving this would be to communicate via a REST API. To do so you would need to use Django rest framework, you can find more info about DRF [Here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/#example).

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to mention AJAX as their code doesn't contain anything that will communicate with the server.

Comment: if "their code doesn't contain anything that will communicate with the server", then AJAX, which is a way to communicate with the server, will not work, by definition. Ajax traditionally communicates via something called a REST API.

Comment: does it will be difficult to achieve?? BTW thanks for your help >_<

Comment: @SahilBanno: it will take time, but the Django rest framework library tries to make it as easy as possible. A rest api basically involves making a lot of URLs that is made just for your Javascript to send to. Like webpages, but not for humans.